# HTML break line not working as needed

Tags: html

I have an application developed with AngularJS. In one of the pages if have something like this:

```
    <h1 align="left">Name: <strong>{{View_This_Person.Name}}</strong></h1>

    <div style="width:100%">
        <table align="left">
            <tbody style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><font size="5">Status</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5">&nbsp : &nbsp</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5"><strong>{{View_This_Person.Status}}</strong></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font size="5">Degree</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5">&nbsp : &nbsp</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5"><strong>{{View_This_Person.Degree}}</strong></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font size="5">Address</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5">&nbsp : &nbsp</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5"><strong>{{View_This_Person.Address}}</strong></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font size="5">Phone</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5">&nbsp : &nbsp</font></td>
                    <td><font size="5"><strong>{{View_This_Person.Phone}}</strong></font></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="One_Article in Articles_Results.Date track by One_Article.ISBN">
    ...
    </div>
```

The table with the Status, Degree, etc. takes about half the width of the screen.

My problem is that the next contents generated through the `ng-repeat` starts at the right of the table instead of below it.

Using `<br>` just moves the start of the `ng-repear` one line down, so I would need to put several `<br>'s` to get it right, which would result in an ugly display since the height of the table is not fixed, and when the user changes with width of the application... well, no need to explain more.

The question is, how do I force the start of the `ng-repeat` to start **AFTER** the table?

Tried to set an empty div with width of 100% in between and didn't help.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated side note: Please, please don't use the `<font>` tag. It's been deprecated for about 20 years now.

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue rather than AngularJS issue. Please check your browser's CSS inspector to see what is causing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @BlazeSahlzen. The only thing I can see is that the height of the `div` wrapping the table is ZERO. Not clear why though. I also checked removing the style clause from this "div" block getting the same result (height=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `align="left"` attributes which basically means `float: left;` in equivalent CSS.

The [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float) property according to MDN,

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, **where text and inline elements will wrap around it**.

This explains why your `div[ng-repeat]` is being pushed to the right instead of below.

One solution to this problem is to put another `div` in-between the two floating divs in the following way:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

What `clear:both;` does is that it negates the effect of `float:left` so that any elements following it is not affected by the `float`.

Comment: Great answer!!!! (provides both a solution and explanation). Many thanks @BlazeSahlzen !!!! Needless to say, it worked.